# Print from TeX to labels that have odd-sized pages

Tags: geometry, paper-size, printing

Is it possible to generate PDF files in TeX that can be printed to odd-format printers, e.g. the [DYMO LabelWriter 450](http://sites.dymo.com/Solutions/Pages/Product_Details.aspx?SegmentName=&cat=LabelWriterPrinters%28DYMO%29&prod=1752266%28DYMO%29&page=1)? This label maker prints to a roll of labels with page/label sizes such as, e.g. 1-1/8" x 3-1/2".

My first thought is a package such as [EnvLab](http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/envlab/elguide.pdf) or [labels](http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/labels/labels.pdf), however both those packages seem to support only standard sized pages with multiple labels on the page in a grid. I couldn't find a package that supported non-standard sized pages.

My second thought is to use the [geometry](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf) package, but I'm not sure if that's a plausible or the best solution.

I'd be very grateful for thoughts and suggestions.

Comment: geometry should work fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Ulrike said, the `geometry` package works fine. You customize the stock size as required in the geometry package definition, and then proceed and define a new label with necessary dimensions. Here's a quick and dirty example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=10in, paperheight=7in]{geometry} % Define paper stock size here

\usepackage[newdimens]{labels}
\numberoflabels=20

% These are the label parameters. Customize to your heart's content.
\LabelCols=5           % Number of columns of labels per page
\LabelRows=4           % Number of rows of labels per page
\LeftPageMargin=7mm    % These four parameters give the
\RightPageMargin=7mm   % page gutter sizes. The outer edges of
\TopPageMargin=15mm    % the outer labels are the specified
\BottomPageMargin=15mm % distances from the edge of the paper.
\InterLabelColumn=2mm  % Gap between columns of labels
\InterLabelRow=0mm     % Gap between rows of labels
\LeftLabelBorder=5mm   % These four parameters give the extra
\RightLabelBorder=5mm  % space used around the text on each
\TopLabelBorder=5mm    % actual label.
\BottomLabelBorder=5mm 

\begin{document}

    % Here's your label definition
    \begin{labels}
        Me
        My address
        My City, State, Zipcode
        My Brother
        His address
        His City, State, Zipcode
    \end{labels}

\end{document}
```

Admittedly, you'll need to do some calculations and assumptions to find all the parameters (assuming your label size is fixed), but here are the handy formulas (from the `labels` package):

`LabelRows × Label height + (LabelRows − 1) × InterLabelRow = paperheight − TopPageMargin − BottomPageMargin`

`LabelColumns × Label width + (LabelColumns − 1) × InterLabelColumn =
paperwidth − LeftPageMargin − RightPageMargin`